# Is it possible to automate a desktop app with winium using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, winium

I want to automate a Windows desktop app with Winium that is based on Java and is run by .bat file.
When I work with it, there is no 'automation Id' in inspect.exe or UIspy.exe ?!

Is it possible? Are there other automation tools to be able to help me in regards.

Can you help me?
Thank you.